# How to get wifi strength on iPhone X

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, wifi, iphone-x

On stanadrd iPhone I am using this code:

```
 UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *subviews = [[[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
    NSString *dataNetworkItemView = nil;
    NSString *wifiNetworkItemView = nil;

    for (id subview in subviews) {
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView") class]]) {
            dataNetworkItemView = subview;
        }
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView") class]]) {
            wifiNetworkItemView = subview;
        }
    }
    int wifiSignalStrength = [[wifiNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"wifiStrengthRaw"] intValue];

   // int carrierSignalStrength = [[dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"signalStrengthRaw"] intValue];

    NSString *strengthString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", wifiSignalStrength];

    callback(@[strengthString]);
```

But this doesn't work for iPhone X.
Any solution? Looks like it doesn't exist. Or is there some solution in React Native?